# Do an extra work for the last iteration

Tags: python

```
mylist = [{'a':1,'b':2},{'a':3,'b':'10'},.....]
I want to do some special operations for the last itemin  loop (iterarale), what to do?

for item in mylist:
   do some operations for all items
   #I want to execute the next statement only for last item

   last_b = item[b] 

last_b
```

What is the best method to do this(with out an if statement)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`item` remains in scope at the end of the loop, and conveniently is the last item, so you just need to dedent that line

```
for item in mylist:
    # do some operations for all items
last_b = item[b]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
for i in range(len(my_list)-1):
     #do stuff till last before element, where i will be the index of the list

my_list[last]=#something
```

This will do seperate iteration only for the last element in the list

Answer (score 1):

Well if it is the last iteration of the loop, then why don't you do that outside the loop itself.